# Mac OS . protected data container, that is not accessible by user or other app

Tags: macos, security, in-app-purchase, local-storage, mac-app-store

We develop app for Mac App Store.
We need that the user can not change some of our apps data. (info about in-app purchases)
Are there any APIs on Mac OS X that can be used for that?
Keychain is not suitable for this, because user can easily modify its contents.
We not considering remote storage of data, because for now we need some kind of local storaging.

Comment: Do you only want to validate the in app purchase or also have the need to protect other data?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such API as the user can get root and admin-privileges to get access to any file or folder on the local-storage.

To validate the In App Purchase use the Store-Kit API documented here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH1-SW23

Alternatively or additionally you may use some kind of encryption and signing to store protected local data.